# best way to keep user logged in using JWT and axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt

how to keep the user always logged in, in a react application.
I can't refresh the token using an expired token, can I ?
my idea is to make the token expiration to null and refresh it in every request for security
so if user don't use the app for a while, token will never expires, and in every request the token will be refreshed for the security

Answer (score 2):

it's not secure to do this. because now the token will still valid as long as no new requests from the user. tokens that never expire extend the time-frame for attacks such as cross-site request forgery (CSRF), session hijacking and session fixation. also if you want to change this behavior you will need to change it from backend side not react.js side

Comment: thank you, so what can i do to keep user logged in ?

Comment: From react.js side, if you don't  control the backend you can only set longer expiry data but if you have control over the back end you can implement endpoint `/token/extend` as an example to fetch a new token from it before the expiry of the current valid token

Answer (score 1):

I might be misreading your question, but at least just on "how to keep user logged in"

You can do this with localStorage, ofcourse there is security concern.

Basic idea: user logins, the user object returns from database, you only need to store the jwt_encoded information that makes a user **"looks like is logged in"** in the localStorage. By that I mean, you aren't going to return the user's password & email everytime, and on refresh page, log the user in with those credentials... If you are building a todolist app, just store the todolist tasks & username to the localStorage after the user logs in for the first time. And then if the user refreshes the page, just display the information from the localStorage.

It might be a little bit more tricky because UI is dynamic and you have to change your localStorage to change your UI, but on backend calls that update our user object, we can simply return the new user object and set that as the new user in localStorage.

Best to check this article for **code**, https://blog.bitsrc.io/build-a-login-auth-app-with-the-mern-stack-part-3-react-components-88190f8db718. The author starts talking it about half way through. I only provided theoretical stuff.

---

Edit: I really was falling asleep. For the "it might be a little bit tricky part" I was being quite dumb. If you saved the user id in the localstorage, you can just make api calls to retrieve the user information with that id whenever you need it, in short, you only need to store user id in localStorage.

Comment: thank you, but my problem is after expiration of the token. we can't refresh it without ask the user to re-login.

Comment: Yea sorry I have trouble deeply understanding jwt and expirations and all that. But I followed that tutorial and just set the token expiration date to 1 year

Comment: and when you refresh it ?

Comment: It is stored in the localStorage and so the information doesn't go away for 1 year unless the user disables cookies & localStorage. And so I guess you refresh it once a year, or it refreshes whenever the user logs out (which we simulate the behavior by removing information from localStorage) and then logs in again

Comment: so it's not possible for someone ( that has access to our device ) to copy the token into his localStorage and login without username and password ?